# Run or use GCC without install

Tags: gcc, fortran, installation, clang, portability

Can I use **GCC** for e.g GCC4.0.3 without installation
In my macOS I have installed Clang xcode , and GCC from Homebrew
In my Linux they are installed as well

But I want to use GCC (Specially older version) besides most updated version
Like **NVM** that manage Node version and it lets you install many **nodejs** with different version on your system

I want to use **GCC4** specially for science and compiling Old **FORTRAN** to make my Source codes run and see the results

In new OS both macOS and Linux when you install gcc it will install most updated and that is not useful for old fortran or old codes.

So In my solution i think its better to use gcc **without install** or even install gcc to **custom directory** folder and copy the codes in that directory and compile them but not to install as wide system and make incompatibility with default GCC and CLANG on system

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always download the source, build it, and install in a custom location.

Comment: ok, but how and how can i make a script for automation this process ?
i want to share it in github for university

Comment: gfortran runs old Fortran just fine. The two commoon soluetions are either to use a package manager such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or to download the binaries from http://coudert.name/software.html

Comment: **"it will install most updated and that is not useful for old fortran or old codes."** This is nonsense. The new versions are backwards compatible and they will fix bugs that can cause problems even in old programs. Alas, the backward compatibility is THE reason to use Fortran for many people. There is no need to use old compilers.

Comment: Just reinforcing @vladmirF in this: always use the most recent posible version of the compiler. Even if a language feature was made obsolete in recent standard version, you can control compiler behavior with options, like -std in Fortran or -stand in Intel.

Comment: how can i use gcc without installing ?
just put download sources and compile source codes in downloaded directory ?

i dont want to install gcc in wide installation, just run or use it locally without install
also some codes need old compilers even the newer versions are backwards compatibles need old libraries
So
How can I use GCC without installing 
just give me some tutorial please thanks

Comment: I agree with @Vladimir about your comment regarding needing an old gfortran for old code.  That is simply nonsense.  If the code contains a number of questionable extensions, then you likely need to use the -std=legacy option.  What actually happens if you try compiling your old code with a newer gfortran?

Comment: 1. This site is not to provide tutorials but to answer questions which are not too broad. 2. I don't know what is "without install" for you. I think you have to always install it. Yes, you can install it to your home directory, but you do have to install it. 3. The steps to compile and install GCC are included with the sources and are also on the web https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC If you ha e problem with these, be specific and tell us what kind of problem it is.

Comment: I just need to know am I have to install or i can use it like a portable compiler and @VladimirF you said that I have to install it

But can I install it in custom directory and not messing up with default gcc installed on system and use it in this way?
for example def gcc installed in /usr/local/bin and xcode clang installed in /usr/bin
Can i install gcc 4.0.3 for e.g in /home/desktop/my-custom-gcc and use in there and after works done delete the folder and FINISHED ???

Comment: @JARVISAI.  Why exactly do you think you need an old 4.0.3 gfortran?  Show us a minimal example of the code that newer gfortran will not compile.

Comment: @Steve thanks to reply, this isn’t just for fortran , I want to use old compiler like gcc and another reason is a challenge in my university class , i have to use old one. So if there is a way to use it , I will really appreciate that tutorial. With my previous comment I refined my request even more clearly!?

Comment: As I know up to now , there isn’t anything like NVM for gcc , something like gcc version manager !

Comment: @JARVISAI, your only choice is to download the tar file from gcc.gnu.org, read the installation instruction, and install gcc-4.0.3 on your system.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks anyway, that’s exactly Im looking for custom directory installation